# Permanent Redirect of the domain and subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, apache2

I have a domain say xyz.com which has to be redirected to abc.com/123 running on apache2. Also the challenge is I have a page xyz.com/blog. When user hits blog.xyz.com it has to be redirected to xyz.com/blog. But when the user types xyz.com it has to be redirected to abc.com/123.

How do I achieve this with apache2. Do help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using wordpress just use a redirect plugin

Comment: I cant use wordpress plugin I have to do it using apache2 config